# Universal Robot: can I access the joint currents in ROS?

Tags: ros, universal-robots, ur-modern-driver, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am successfully able to command my UR10 from a ROS node.  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic, the ROS [universal robot](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot) package, and the ROS [ur_modern_driver](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver) package (plus a minor code fix that I found on the Internet to make it compile under Ubuntu 16.04).

When I use the pendant to control the arm, I occasionally look at the joint current amperage values on the log tab in order to make decisions.  Mostly when picking up payloads or dropping them off.  Is there a way to access the real-time joint currents from ROS?  Or am I just trying to do it all wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271893/universal-robot:-can-i-access-the-joint-currents-in-ros?/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `i_actual` field from the 'real-time interface' datastream is currently being used to populate the `effort` field of the `JointState` msg published on the `/joint_state` topic (see [RosWrapper::publishRTMsg() - line 676](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/blob/fe9762e9d52b20bf6d1640bd8d046db27b0774d1/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp#L676)).

See document `16496` on the UR support site for more information about what `i_actual` actually represents.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2017-10-02**:
Wow.  Thanks!  I noticed this effort field when I first installed the UR drivers, but I didn't understand what it was for.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
Note that I'm not entirely convinced that using `i_actual` like that for `effort` is correct. But that is orthogonal to your question.